# Carrierwave: how to handle multiple uploads of the same type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

currently I am having an Article model with one carrierwave uploader, requirements have changed and every Article should have n images attached.

What is the best (and most simple) way to achieve this? Right now, all I can think of is creating an Image entity and have this reference the uploader and let have every Article n Images. Sounds like a lot of work and would break all current images, so I would not favor this.

Answer (score 1):

It might be better if you do split out the image uploading requirements into its own model. Your Article model has already changed the requirements and you might have other models needing similar functionality later on.

From the software design point of view, having an Image model that deals with uploading and relating that to an Article model is a more maintainable way.

Comment: I am shying away from the interface part of it. And there might be hidden n+1s in a lot of lists. It would be great if carrierwave could handle this somehow.

Comment: The problem with carrierwave handling it is that it adds complexity to a library already burdened with the details of saving the files in the expected place, whether that's S3 or otherwise.

This is really an app-level decision, but if you're able to extend carrierwave to get the requirement, go for it.